# changed name of membership database, can't find users

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I created an asp.net site using VS 2008. I was using a db in app_data for membership. I am moving this to a new server and the db will be attached to a sql server 2008 R2 instance. I wanted to change the db name so it would fit in better with the rest of the server. Since I changed the name from ASPNETDB.mdf to Reporting.MDF I cannot login and ASP.NET says I have no users. I used the rename function in VS and updated my connectionstring.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MembershipConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Reporting.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <!--added to create new membership to connect to-->
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" applicationName="WebSite2" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
<providers>
 <clear/>
<add connectionStringName="MembershipConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
 enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="WebSite2"
 requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
 minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
 passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
 name="SqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
</providers>
</membership>
```

Users: 0
Provider: Test to check db works fine.

edit: I removed the publicKey in case it is tied to me in some way.

edit: I changed the name back to aspnetdb and it still does not work.

If i delete the membership code it works again. This is after changing the name back to aspnetdb. I am back where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by opening machine.config and copying all of the membership details. Then used
     clear 
in every section.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="LocalSqlServer2" connectionString="Data Source=Johnny;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <!--added to create new membership to connect to-->
  <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer2" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer2" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="/>
    </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer2" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="/>
      <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="/>
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have this problem again it's likely caused by forgetting to properly set the `applicationName` attribute in `web.config`. Here's a [great, detailed explanation of the common problem](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/Always-set-the-_2200_applicationName_2200_-property-when-configuring-ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-other-Providers.aspx). If you compare the `web.config` file from your *question* to your `web.config` in your *answer*, you'll see that the `applicationName` attributes in the two files have **different** values; `WebSite2` versus `/`.

Comment: I gave this a thumbs up for being a useful resource. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the aspnetdb database first. Then rename it using Sql Management Studio.